# AD5242 to generate a current source

Tags: arduino, i2c, embedded, potentiometer, digital-potentiometer

[image: Current generation circuit with AD5242 (1MOhm) programmable potentiometer]

[image: AD5242 PCB schematic]

We are trying to program the potentiometer with I2C using Arduino Due. The SCL-SDA of AD5242 are connected on the SCL-SDA (D20-D21) of the Arduino.
We are using MATLAB to program and operate the Arduino and in-turn the programmable potentiometer.

```
clearvars; clc
a = arduino('COM3', 'Due', 'Libraries', 'I2C');


tmp102 = device(a,'I2CAddress','0x2E');

%%writing to AD5242 RDAC resgister
write(tmp102, 0x5C, 'uint8'); %%Slave address byte
write(tmp102, 0x00, 'uint8'); %%Instruction byte
write(tmp102, 0x00, 'uint8'); %%Data byte


%%read back RDAC register value
write(tmp102, 0x5D, 'uint8'); %%Slave address byte
out = read(tmp102, 1)
```

The output always returns 128 (which indicates that the pot is reset during power ON), however, we are unable to program the RDAC register. [AD5242 datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5241_5242.pdf)

**What are we missing?**

Comment: Well you're either not writing correctly or not reading correctly or both so, rule one out by measuring the resistance change on the pot when you write to it. If the pot value changes then you know it's a read problem.

Comment: We are not detecting any change in resistance value as well. When we measure the resistance with a multi-meter we observe 0.5MOhm resistance which corresponds to 128.

Comment: Then concentrate on the write side of things.

Comment: Yes, we have been debugging the write part. We checked the SDA and SCL lines on the oscilloscope, and observed that the SDA line has the slave address byte and the data byte, however, the instruction byte is missing. On the other hand, when we send only the data byte, the Arduino appends the slave address before the data byte.

Comment: I don't think there's any further help I can give you. It's a soft issue now.